# Hosting with Static/Fixed IP Address

Tags: hosting, ip, host, static-ip-address

I have been search for a host that has static/fixed ip address.  Right now i use mediatemple's grid server and because it is a shared environment the ip address is dynamic and changes randomly.

My issue is that i have a script on my sever that fetches data from an ftp site.  To access the data via ftp, i have to authenticate using an ip address, username and password.  Because the ip address is ever changing, i cannot access the data.

One alternative was asking the data company if they would accept a range of ip address or a wildcard but they will not. they will only approve one ip address for download.

The other option was to purchase a self managed server.  I do not want to manage my own server nor do i have the expertise to do so.  So I need a solution like a shared environment (low cost) with a cpanel but one that has fixed ip address.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.  Godaddy vps virtual server starting at only $29.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for "managed server" or "VPS" solutions.

Which host you choose is up to you. Many hosts offer such solutions, and a smaller host might fit your budget better than a "big name" hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

This is really surprising ... usually in a shared hosting account where your site is hosted on a shared IP, the shared IP address is always fixed it rarely changes. I think you're right now on CDN hosting, so your data delivery IP address varies according to your VISITOR location.

I am hosting my various sites like thewebhostingdir.com and etc at http://www.accuwebhosting.com/ ... on shared hosting and their IP address is fixed since the hosting setup.

I suggest you to change your hosting provider. You don't need VPS at this moment.